# Python3.3 code conversion from 2.7 using API auth functions thows TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, argparse

what is causing the TypeError? i am at a loss. so here is my following code. i have sort of debugged this. as you can see the print lines  the authentication code is not mine it is borrowed from a co-worker who is not here. none of this code should be confidential and for the most part generic but i have never run into this situation before. it is getting a string and expecting byte code?

```
#! /bin/python3.3/
import argparse
import configparser
import getpass
import sys
import urllib
from lxml import objectify, etree
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

#""" start authentication """
sys.path.append("Lib")
from vCloudSessionObj import vCloudSessionObj
from vCloudRequestObj import vCloudRequestObj

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--hostname')
    #print("-h")
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--username')
    #print("-u")
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--organization', required=True)
    #print("-o")
    return parser
#print("into parser")

#python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    sessionObj = vCloudSessionObj( args.hostname,args.username,getpass.getpass(), args.organization)
    validity = sessionObj.is_valid()
    if validity is False:
        print("Login Failed")
        sys.exit()

    requestObj = vCloudRequestObj(sessionObj)

    QueryResultRecords = requestObj.get('/api/admin/extension/vapps/query')



#"""start new process... create new vApp"""
def getcatalog():

        GET /catalogs/query # this will make a list of catalogues to choose from

        catalogID = raw_input("please enter the catalogue id: ") #"""for inputting the catalog id"""

        #"""makes use of the catalogID variable from the raw input and gets the selected catalogue"""
        GET /catalog/catalogID


def GetNewVapp():

        vappID = raw_input("please enter the vApp ID: ") #"""for inputting the vApp ID"""
        POST /vApp/vappID/action/deploy         #"""api call to deploy the catalogued vApp ID"""
```

it outputs to this:

```
[root@64-CentOS-2 Python-3.3.0]# python3.3 deployVapp.py -H host -u myname -o myorg
into parser
-h
-u
-o
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deployVapp.py", line 31, in <module>
    sessionObj = vCloudSessionObj( args.hostname,args.username,getpass.getpass(), args.organization)
  File "Lib/vCloudSessionObj.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.auth_token = self.initialize_auth_token(hostname, username, password, organization)
  File "Lib/vCloudSessionObj.py", line 44, in initialize_auth_token
    username, organization, password))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    raise TypeError("expected bytes, not %s" % s.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: expected bytes, not str
```

Comment: What's `GET /catalogs/query` supposed to do? I don't see anything that could have introduced a `GET` object with a weird overloaded division operator. Are you sure you didn't copy/paste pseudocode into your program?

Comment: I'm not seeing any hits for `vCloudSessionObj` on Google, so that looks like something internal to your organization. It seems that either you're passing the wrong arguments to its constructor, or it wasn't properly updated for Python 3. Some `str` needs to be `bytes`; back in Python 2, those were the same type, but `str` is unicode now.

Comment: Also, `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3.x, you should never be testing things like `validity is False` (use `not validity`), and you probably want to exit with an error status (e.g., `sys.exit(1)`) and maybe print something, instead of silently existing with success.

Comment: The authentication script was not written by me it was written by a co-worker. I am just in charge of bringing it up to version 3.x that info helps a lot. vCloudSessionObj is internally written but it uses 3rd party libraries. The GET call is to VMware's Vitural Cloud Director(VCD) API which is what vCloudSessionObj initializes an authentication for. the goal here being to launch a vApp from a catalog into VCD unfortunately I can not provide vCloudSessionObj as it has proprietary/protected info inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string in Python 3 is a Unicode string (sequence of Unicode codepoints). `bytes` is a sequence of bytes (an integer 0..255).

`expected bytes, not str` error message means that `initialize_auth_token()` method should be changed to encode a Unicode text into bytes before calling `b64encode()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much I will test this out tomorrow and see how it works. ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: So i finally figured it out. within vCloudSessionObj.py i had to find where it was formatting the credentials and convert the inside of the function if was calling into byte code. thank you for your help it certainly put me on the right track.

Comment: @castaway2000: ["byte code" is *unrelated* to your case in any way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (there are java bytecode, python bytecode (look inside `.pyc` files), etc). Don't confuse it with the word "bytes".

Comment: Oh thank you for correcting my use of words ill make sure to differentiate the two in the future. Now I am off to do some API work. Thanks again for the help on the code.